# Access DuckDuckGo without HTTPS?

Tags: https, duckduckgo

Is there a way to use DuckDuckGo search without HTTPS? My internet access blocks HTTPS by default.

Is there an option I can put after `duckduckgo.com/?opt=val` that disables HTTPS? For example, Google allows `http://www.google.com/?nord=1`, which bypasses HTTPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: go to http://duckduckgo.com/?kh=-1

You can pass the parameter `kh=-1` as stated in [DDG's params reference](http://duckduckgo.com/params):

> **Privacy Settings**
>
> Redirect: kd = 1 for On; -1 for Off.
>   HTTPS:    kh = 1 for On; -1 for Off.

Answer (score 3):

The "DuckDuckGo Settings" are available over HTTP (without SSL/TLS) at:
http://duckduckgo.com/settings/?kh=-1
...as any other page of DuckDuckGo with `kh=-1` parameter.
And on a ["Privacy" tab](http://duckduckgo.com/settings?kh=-1#privacy) of the settings page you can change the "HTTPS" setting ("Use encrypted version of the site") to "Off" value and save it in a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable https from [DuckDuckGo settings](https://duckduckgo.com/settings)

Comment: How can I access the settings without https?

Comment: hm, that's not possible, /settings requires https. If you can edit the cookies, probably change the cookie "h" value to -1, that seems to disable https for search

Comment: I don't have any cookies associated with duckduckgo. Can I create one or something? I am using ubuntu, firefox.